# want to make rest client page with php

Tags: php, html, xml, rest, curl

this is the code i want to take details from user and wnat to use 1.rest 2.post method 3.xml 4.php code, dont want to use cURL .in the find.php file i want to json to xml and is there way that i can do it without curl?

this is function.php

```html
<?php
function get_price($find){
             $books=array(
    "java"=>300,
    "c"=>250,
    "php"=>350);
    foreach($books as $books=>$price)
    {
        
     if($books==$find)
     {
     return $price;
     break;
     }
    }
    
    
    }
    ?>
```

this code is for index.php

```html
<?php
       header("content-Type:application/json");
    include("function.php");
    if(!empty($_GET['name'])){
    
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $price = get_price($name);
    
    if(empty($price)){
         deliver_response(200,"book not found",NULL);
    }    
    else{
         deliver_response(200,"book found",$price);
    
                }    
    }
    else{
            deliver_response(400,"invalid",NULL);
    }
    
    function deliver_response($status,$status_message,$data)
    {
    header("HTTP/1.1 $status $status_message");
    
     $response['status']=$status;
  $response['status_message']=$status_message;
  $response['data']=$data;
  
  $json_response=json_encode($response);
  echo $json_response;
    
    
    }
    ?>
```

the error is in this code where i want to use xml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
<head>

    <title>Rest</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>ENTER BOOK :</h2> 
    <form action = "" method = "POST">
     <input type = "text" name = "name" /> <br />
      <input type = "submit" name = "submit" /> 
    </form>
 
 <?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  $name = $_POST['name'];
     
   $url="http://localhost/rest/find.php?name=$name"; 
   $client=curl_int($url);
   
   curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $response=curl_exec($client);
   $result=simplexml_load_file($response);
   echo $result->data;
   print_r($result);

   ?>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Better use frameworks like slim instead of reinventing the whole wheel

Comment: you can help me with this only @bub